# Getting Error While Creating the superuser in Terminal

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

[image][image: Getting the Attribute Error. I'm not sure what else can be wrong in my models.py.]

**AttributeError: 'UserManager' object has no attribute 'create_superuser'**

Comment: show your code, not a screenshot of code

Comment: moreover, it seems the indentation of manager methods are not correct.

Comment: **tried doing indentation but still getting the same error**.

Answer (score 0):

You have created "create_superuser" and "create_user" as a functions. Create these functions as methods of UserManager class

Comment: Please share your code, there is an issue with your indentation

Answer (score 0):

Your indentations are incorrect.
Add one level of indentation to `create_user` and `create_superuser` functions so they belong to the `UserManager` class

Comment: **tried doing indentation** but still getting the same error.

Comment: please edit your message and add your code, if you need more help